# fsockopen problems, strange behaivor

Tags: php, fsockopen

I installed same script on 2 different servers but on one this code works:

```
fsockopen($this->getServer(), $this->port, $error_number, $error_string,$this->connectionTimeout);
```

Values of params are:

```
$this->getServer() = tcp://mail.....
$this->port = 587
```

One first, I opened connection but on second I couldn't.
Used this as check :

```
if (empty($this->socket)) {
        return false;
    }
```

This if return `false` on first and on second `true` but on the same configuration

Someone know the reason? Maybe apache? Some configuration?

Comment: OK so what if anything is returned in `$error_number` and `$error_string` when it does not work?

Comment: Want me to tell you values of $error_number and $error_string?

Comment: Yes, that is where the command put any errors that occur during connection

Comment: You might also like to [check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for how it is recommended to check for a good or failed connection

Comment: $error_string is 'Permission denied'

Comment: Well there is your answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my day :) This is fix for me  setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1